# Strange pixelation/vertical lines after MPEG4/H.263 encode

Tags: video, video-encoding, mpeg-4

I have been trying to encode video data (H.263 and MPEG4) from a USB camera on an embedded device. The device has a special hardware to do it.

But after encoding the raw video from the USB camera (H.263/MPEG4) the video quality becomes bad and some strange pixelations and vertical lines occur in the video. In [this image](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Ej-_nvMOiYI/TmSMYa7ZvNI/AAAAAAAAA0U/PmZKLzXGj8I/s640/vlcsnap-2011-09-05-11h42m19s245.png) you can see the annoying vertical lines. The [second image](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-sNsL_qojfCY/TmSJ_O8evLI/AAAAAAAAA0Q/_N5NUdZhKWo/s912/photo.JPG) is an example of displaying the raw video and the encoded video together;
the right side is the display result from raw data (good quality), and on the left side is after encode. Is this problem a known pattern ? What causes these vertical lines ?

The properties of USB video data: 15 fps, QCIF, YUV420P.

By the way the image quality becomes a lot better when I display the video on a half-width area (with SDL); that is displaying the QCIF video on a 88x144 rectangle. The quality doesn't change when I change the height of the display area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

seems like bad image format conversion, especially wrong width/height or strand parameters

Comment: The only image format conversion done is from YUV 4:2:2 to YUV 4:2:0. No rescaling or any other operation has been made on the original video stream. Strangely, when I convert the encoded (and distorted) image to YUV 4:2:0 and do the encoding operation again, the combo-like artifact disappears and the display is okay. I can't really understand the reason.